# My draggable function has broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I had a draggable function and it was working nicely. But when I add NO-2 function, my draggabe function and my close button(button which included the div) broke down. Need help.

NO-1: Draggable function:

```
$(function () {
    $('#draggable').draggable({
        containment: 'window'
    });
    $('#draggable').draggable({
        handle: '.yeniyorum_baslik'
    });
});
```

NO-2: This function for post data without refresh the available page.

```
function kayitol() {
    $('.yeniyorum_div, .arka_fon').hide() $('#urunsayfaid').removeClass('noscroll');
    $('.yorum_basarili').fadeIn() $('.yorum_basarili').fadeOut(4000) var veriler = $('.yorumform').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "yorum_ekle.php",
        data: veriler,
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function kayitol() {
    $('.yeniyorum_div, .arka_fon').hide() $('#urunsayfaid').removeClass('noscroll');
    $('.yorum_basarili').fadeIn();
    $('.yorum_basarili').fadeOut(4000);
    var veriler = $('.yorumform').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "yorum_ekle.php",
        data: veriler,
    })
};
```

Comment: This time button's not working. This button opens the draggable menu which has close button I said.